# Karate #regex failed to match string ending with a number

Tags: regex, automated-tests, karate

I am trying to match the string ending with a number `"Invalid Version. Latest known Version is 110"`

The regex matcher I used was:

```
"#regex ^.+\d+"
```

When running the test the output was:

> actual: 'Invalid Version. Latest known Version is 110', expected: '#regex ^.+d+', reason: regex match failed

Answer (score 1):

This worked:
`"#regex ^.+\\d+"`

I missed that I need to put double backslash `\\`.